# Find key in array, and array_push in that key

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array with random keys (it's a menu builder to be pushed to json). So in this multi-dimensional i'm trying to array_push some more details. But here's the thing, I don't know the key or dimension in the array. I only know the key.

So what I'm trying to do is below.

```
$arr[unique_key1] = value;
$arr[unique_key1][unique_key2] = 'value';
$arr[unique_key1][unique_key2][unique_key3] = 'value';
$arr[unique_key1][unique_key2][unique_key3][unique_key4] = 'value';

$key = unique_key4; // (example) key to look for and array push

if (array_key_exists($key, $arr)) { // check to be sure, should be there
    // here I want to loop until i found the specific key, and on that place array_push
}
else {
    // error handeling
}
```

the $arr in this example is simple, but the real one contains about 800 entry's in different layers.

So to sum up:

1. Find key in big array (it is still unique)
2. array_push to that part of the array.

Much obliged

EDIT: explained in more detail, wasn't clear enough

Comment: A recursive function to find a key in a multidimensional array would be what you are looking for, plenty of examples on google ..

Answer (score 0):

i think this is what you want.. from below code you will get to know the key and do what you want...

```
 if ($array_in_which_we_can_add = multi_array_key_exists($key, $arr)) { 
        array_push($array_in_which_we_can_add, 'crap I want to add');
    }
    else {
        // error handeling
    }



function multi_array_key_exists( $needle, $haystack ) {


foreach ( $haystack as $key => $value ) :

    if ( $needle == $key )
        return $key;

    if ( is_array( $value ) ) :
         if ( multi_array_key_exists( $needle, $value ) == true )
            return true;
         else
             continue;
    endif;

endforeach;

return false;}
```

**EDIT:**

this will do exactly what you wanted

```
if ($array_in_which_we_can_add = multidimensionalArrayMap($needle, $haystack)) { 
   print_r($array_in_which_we_can_add);
}
else {
    // error handeling
}

$flag = 0;

function multidimensionalArrayMap( $needle, $haystack ) {
    $newArr = array();

    foreach( $haystack as $key => $value )
    {
        if($key == $needle)
        $flag = 1;
        $newArr[ $key ] = ( (is_array( $value ) && $key != $needle)  ? multidimensionalArrayMap($needle, $value ) :'crap I want to add' );
    }

    if($flag)
    return $newArr;

    return false;

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing, but I have been messing around with this and it does not do what it needs to do.

I know the key, I just don't know where in the dimension it is. So I don't need a function that searches a key, I need a way to add something to that key. 

So, go to the right dimension at the right key, and then add add an array.

Comment: Hm. What exactly do you know about the key? $arr[unique_key1][unique_key2][unique_key3][unique_key4][] = 'some other value'; would be the obvious way to insert...

Comment: Found another way around. But thank you all very much for yours input.